# If a is an arbitrary integer, then $6|a(a^2+11)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Pprove: If a is an arbitrary integer, then $6|a(a^2+11)$

So I substituted $k+1$ in for a and for my final step I have:

$6|k^3+3k^2+14k+12$

At this point what I have left isn't divisible by $6$ so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Step by step explanation please!

Comment: Are you using mathematical induction?  This is possible but the answers given below are easier.

Comment: using Maxima
   `makelist(mod(a*(a^2+11),6),a,0,5);` gives 
   `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: yeah I am using mathematical induction

Answer (score 3):

Since $6|12$ and $6|a(a+1)(a-1)$, $6|a(a^2-1),$ (product of three sequential numbers is divisible by 6), we have that $6|(12 a+a(a+1)(a-1))$, $6|a(a^2+11)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using your approach, if we consider $k^3+3k^2+14k+12$ modulo $6$, this is equivalent to $k^3+3k^2+2k=k(k+1)(k+2)$ modulo $6$. Note that at least one of $k,k+1,k+2$ is even, and at least one of these is divisible by $3$, so the product must be divisible by $6$. Thus our original expression must be divisible by $6$.

Comment: how is k3+3k2+14k+12  equivalent to k3+3k2+2k??

Comment: If $k^3+3k^2+2k$ is divisible by $6$, then $12k+12$ is divisible by $6$ also, so their sum $(k^3+3k^2+2k)+(12k+12)=k^3+3k^2+14k+12$ is divisible by $6$ as well.

Comment: how do we know k3+3k2+2k is divisible by 6?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
(a+1)((a+1)^2+11)-a(a^2+11)
&=(a+1)^3+11(a+1)-a^3-11a\\
&=a^3+3a^2+3a+1+11a+11-a^3-11a\\
&=3a^2+3a+12\\
&=3(a^2+a+4)\\
&=3(a(a+1)+4)\\
\end{array}
$

$a(a+1)$ 
is even,
so
$a(a+1)+4$
is even,
so
$3(a(a+1)+4)$
is divisible by $6$.

Therefore,
if
$a(a^2+11)$
is divisible by 6,
so is
$(a+1)((a+1)^2+11)$.
Since
$a(a^2+11) = 12$
for $a=1$,
$a(a^2+11)$
is divisible by 6
for all $a$.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to show that $a^3 + 11a\equiv a^3 + 5a\equiv 0\pmod 6$ for $S=\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$. Then

- $(-2)^3+5(-2)\equiv -18 \equiv 0\pmod 6$
- $(-1)^3+5(-1)\equiv -6\equiv 0\pmod 6$
- $0^3+5(0)\equiv 0\pmod 6$
- $1^3+5(1)\equiv 6\equiv 0\pmod 6$
- $2^3+5(2)\equiv 18\equiv 0\pmod 6$
- $3^3+5(3)\equiv 42\equiv 0\pmod 6$.